# NodeJS soap request "Invalid WSDL URL"

Tags: node.js, soap

I'm trying to make a request to a web service with a URL similar to the following:

http://91.21.24.521:7831/XXXXX/WS/{companyName}/XXXXX/XXXX?wsdl

I've blanked out some information with the XXXX, but that's the basic structure of the URL. The company name actually has blank spaces. I've tried making the request with the blank spaces and filling them with %20, but neither work. The URL works fine in Soap UI, where I fill the blank spaces with %20.

In Javascript I'm using the "soap" NPM module. And my current code looks like this:

```
  const auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${user}:${password}`).toString('base64')
  const options = {
    wsdl_headers: {
      'Authorization': auth,
      forceSoap12Headers: true,
      disableCache: true,
    }
  }
soap.createClient(url, options, function (err, client) {
  console.log(err, client)
})
```

When I inspect the console log, I get an undefined client and an error that says Invalid WSDL URL.

I've tried removing the options, trying different version of the URL, changing the options object structure but nothing seems to work. I'me confused because the URL works fine in Soap UI and the web browswer, but doesn't work in this scenario. Is there something wrong with the code?

Thanks